# String value that represents an email attachment, how to store to disk/db?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, file, io

Ok it turns out this 3rd party component I am working with stores an email attachment in a property of string type (it is already decoded).

How would I store this to file now?

It has: filename, encodingtype and the string representation of the file.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What does "encodingtype" refer to? The MIME Content-Transfer-Encoding or a .NET System.Text.Encoding or something else?

Comment: How can be the "decoded" file stored in a string? Your app supports only textural (non-binary) files?

Answer (score 2):

Open a file using a StreamWriter/TextWriter class and call the .Write method. Alternatively you can base64 encode it with Convert.ToBase64String first.